# query to get data from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

model1

---

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const finalApprovalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  formId: String,
  designApproval: String,
  rejectionReason: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
const FinalApproval = mongoose.model("FinalApproval", finalApprovalSchema);
module.exports = FinalApproval;
```

---

2nd model

---

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const DesignApprovalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  formId: String,
  finalDesignFile: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
const DesignApproval = mongoose.model("DesignApproval", DesignApprovalSchema);
module.exports = DesignApproval;
```

---

i stored these formId in

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const formsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  clientId: { type: String, required: true },
  forms: [
    {
      formId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
  },
});

const Forms = mongoose.model("Forms", formsSchema);
module.exports = Forms;
```

i want to output as

```
[
 {
    "formId": "d8721ee0-d306-4370-88bc-9d071ac87a58",
    "shipmentData": Object {

 "1": Object {
       "__v": 0,
        "_id": "60c999cc912ead3d30d4177a",
        "date": "2021-06-16T06:27:24.516Z",
        "designApproval": "approved",
        "formId": "ef954086-c1d2-4a31-a891-ce6a94415a31",
        "rejectionReason": "",
      },
      "2": Object {
        "__v": 0,
        "_id": "60c999c6912ead3d30d41779",
        "date": "2021-06-16T06:27:18.764Z",
        "finalDesignFile": "",
        "formId": "ef954086-c1d2-4a31-a891-ce6a94415a31",
      },


}}]
```

please help me to retrieve the data as shown. I have tried using the mongoose aggregate method but the result is not as expected. below are the steps which i have followed:

1. I have clientId only.
2. find formId form **Forms** model then i want to use these formIds to
3. find Other Models data and show as format provided

Answer (score 0):

you can try the bellow query to achieve your expected output

```
Forms.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "clientId": "String"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$forms"
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "FinalApproval", // collection name in the db
        localField: "forms.formId", // field in the Forms collection
        foreignField: "formId", // field in the FinalApproval collection
        as: "finalApprovalData"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "DesignApproval", // collection name in the db
        localField: "forms.formId", // field in the Forms collection
        foreignField: "formId", // field in the FinalApproval collection
        as: "designApprovalData"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        formId: "$formId",
        "shipmentData.0": "$finalApprovalData",
        "shipmentData.1": "$designApprovalData",
    }
}
])
```

below are steps that have been followed in the aggregation pipeline

- filtered data based on the clientId`{ $match: { "clientId": "String" }}`
- unwinded data for formsIds `{ $unwind: "$forms" }`
- tried lookup in the **DesignApproval** and **FinalApproval**.
- finally, projected the data in the manner you want the output to be.

Comment: thanks @rohanraj .query output is not expected. but idea really help me

Comment: output :{
        "_id": "60c9e3ac44e2e43e346ae0b9",
        "shipmentData": {
            "0": []
        }
    },

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching your problem in a way you think more about relational schemas. Anyways you can insert references to other documents and launch a query with populate keyword that will follow that reference and retrieve the contents.

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
postedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
comments: [{
    text: String,
    postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}]
});
```

Then to retrieve the data inside the document at runtime you need to launch a query with:

```
 Post.find({})
        .populate('postedBy')
        .populate('comments.postedBy')
        .exec(function(error, posts) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(posts, null, "\t"))
        });
```

I think this is the approach you're a looking for.

But, yeah otherwise to query over multiple document collections you need an aggregation.

Comment: thanks @not.Rick.Sanchez  for answering. but i want to retrive data in single query